# Animation with StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

#### Project

Hi,
I have created with flutter a simple app that changes the height of a container with a streambuilder based on user vertical drag.

So because user input updates are very fast, this force the streambuider to rebuild multiple times, creating the effect of an animation.

#### Code

```
    final StreamController streamController = StreamController<double>();
    double height = 0.0;

    StreamBuilder(
      initialData: 0.0,
      stream: streamController.stream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return Container(
          height: snapshot.data,
        );
      },
    ),

     ....

     height += (dragUpdateDY);
     streamController.add(height);
```

#### Problem

Despite code is working as intended, I keep thinking that this is not a good solution because it forces the UI to rebuild an unpredictable amount of time in a second, maybe even beyond 60 times, exceeding display refresh rate.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is totally fine because `build` is actually **not** called by you! It is always called by the framework, which is why it will not be called more than 60 Hz.
This is true because `StreamBuilder` calls [`State.setState`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) internally, which does the following:

> Calling [setState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) notifies the framework that the internal state of this object has changed in a way that might impact the user interface in this subtree, which causes the framework to schedule a [build](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/build.htmlhttps://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/build.html) for this [State](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html) object.

If you want more fine-grained control, you can create your own [`RenderObject`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderObject-class.html) and call [`markNeedsPaint`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderObject/markNeedsPaint.html) or [`markNeedsLayout`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderObject/markNeedsLayout.html) whenever you need it based on [`GestureRecognizer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/GestureRecognizer-class.html)s.